# Angular Material 2 Spinner with Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material2

With the help of existing angular material tutorial on coursetro, I was able to try http and subscribe scenarios with Angular 4 & Angular Material controls. As i was fetching all the photos at first place I see a lag in UI. Hence I've thought of implementing Spinner which gives impression of loading of data md-progress-spinner, but for some reason spinner doesn't show up & moreover I don't see any console logs too, Could you please advise?

**spinner.service.ts:**

```ts
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';


@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
    public status: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
    private _active: boolean = false;

    public get active(): boolean {
        return this._active;
    }

    public set active(v: boolean) {
        this._active = v;
        this.status.next(v);
    }

    public start(): void {
        this.active = true;
    }

    public stop(): void {
        this.active = false;
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts:**

```ts
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SpinnerComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MdButtonModule,
        MdMenuModule,
        MdCardModule,
        MdToolbarModule,
        MdIconModule,
        MdProgressSpinnerModule
    ],
    providers: [SpinnerService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts:**

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    myData: Array<any>;

    constructor(private http:Http,private spinner: SpinnerService) {
        this.spinner.start();
        this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
                 .map(response => response.json())
                 .subscribe(res => this.myData = res,
                            error => console.error(error),
                            () => this.spinner.stop()
                           );
     }
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```html
<app-spinner>Spinning...</app-spinner>

<md-toolbar color="primary">

    <span>MyCompany</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu"><md-icon>menu</md-icon> Menu</button>

</md-toolbar>

<md-menu #appMenu="mdMenu">
    <button md-menu-item> Settings </button>
    <button md-menu-item> Help </button>
</md-menu>

<md-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let data of myData; let i = index">

    <!--<md-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let data of (myData ? myData.slice(0,10): []); let i = index"> -->

    <img md-card-image src="{{ data.url }}">
    <md-card-header>
        <md-card-title>{{ data.title }}</md-card-title>
    </md-card-header>

    <md-card-actions>
        <button md-button>LIKE</button>
        <button md-button>SHARE</button>
    </md-card-actions>
</md-card>
```

**spinner.component.ts:**

```ts
 @Component({
     selector: 'app-spinner',
     templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.css']
 })
 export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

     public active: boolean;

     public constructor(private spinner: SpinnerService) {
         spinner.status.subscribe((status: boolean) => {
             this.active = status;
         });
     }

     ngOnInit(){
         this.spinner.stop(); // or do it on some other event eg: when xmlhttp request completes loading data for the component
     }

     ngOnDestroy(){
         this.spinner.start();
     }

 }
```

**spinner.component.html:**

```html
 <div *ngIf="active">
     <md-progress-spinner mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-spinner>
 </div>
```

Please check if I've made any errors in loading the spinner and my vision is to have this spinner used across multiple components within multiple subscribing calls by having the app-spinner selector mentioned in only `app.component.html`, could you please advise if above approach holds good & any changes required?

Comment: In my case spinner is showing up and my spinner control is in app.component.html --> <app-loader>  </app-loader>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> --> I can see the spinner but the background is not greyed out.. how to keep the spinner but grey out the background in my case <router-outlet> ?? did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this  :

**Create a service with an event Emmitter**

```
   import { Injectable , EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

   @Injectable()
   export class SpinnerService {
   public spinnerActive: EventEmitter<Boolean>;
   constructor() {
   this.spinnerActive = new EventEmitter();

   }

   activate(){
   this.spinnerActive.emit(true)
   }

   deactivate(){
   this.spinnerActive.emit(false)
   }

}
```

**In your app.component.ts**

```
    constructor(private http: Http , private spinnerService : SpinnerService){
     this.spinnerService.spinnerActive.subscribe(active => 
     this.toggleSpinner(active)); 
     }
    toggleSpinner(active){
      console.log("inside Toggle Spinner")
      this.activeSpinner = active
    }
```

And your activeSpinner could be used like this in your template :

`<md-spinner *ngIf="activeSpinner"></md-spinner>`

Activate and deactivate your spinner via `activate` and `deactivate` service methods.

For this to work from anywhere , make sure your spinner is elavated (`z-index`) and `position fixed` so that the spinner comes on top of everything that has been rendered above it (if ever).

Comment: How would be be loaded in an overlay on top of my form, for instance? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of different methods, have a variable which is directly set from the component where you want to implement the `spinner` . So for example

Your spinner.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loader.component.css']
})
export class LoaderComponent{
  @Input() show:boolean;
}
```

HTML :

```
 <div *ngIf="show">
      <md-spinner></md-spinner>
    </div>
```

Component where you would like to use your `spinner`.

```
<app-loader [show]="showLoader">

  </app-loader>
```

And in your TS just set the value of `showLoader` to true/false.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but my second query refers to having app-spinner or app-loader selector placed only once in app.component.html and the spinner should be loaded based on the spinner service flag which can be set/reset in multiple components.

Comment: you can use this in any multiple components you like. `loader` component is seperate

Comment: Ok, but if you see my files or request it targets to have the loader component's selector declared only once in the app component for instance and on need basis the rest of the components will have to use start or stop spinner based on subscription to the service..

Answer (score 0):

I got the spinner elements in the DOM, but I couldn't see it, this is the way I solved:

In html component:

```
<mat-progress-spinner mode="indeterminate" [diameter]="28"></mat-progress-spinner>
```

In app.module.ts:

```
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatProgressSpinnerModule],
  exports: [
    MatProgressSpinnerModule
  ]
```

and in style.css:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```